# How to run a curl script multiple times using windows command prompt

Tags: php, windows, curl, command-line, scripting

I am a total novice at scripting, and need some help in curl scripting. I need to access a URL multiple times using CURL script in Windows command prompt, So that would need calling curl script multiple times.
Is there any way to : 
(A) access the URL request multiple times using single curl script, 
(B) or a way in command prompt to call the single curl script multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

To execute a curl program 3 times, try...

```
for /L %i in (1,1,3) do your_curl_script
```

The last number in (1,1,3) controls your looping count.

NOTE:  This is a solution to your (B) option.  You could put your CURL code inside a batch file and call the batch file X number of times.  The DOS command line would look slightly different, as such:

```
for /L %i in (1,1,3) do your_batch_file
```

Comment: You can put your CURL commands within a batch file and the call the batch file instead as noted in the updated response above.